# Cannot query contract methods after upgrading to geth 1.9

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, geth-clique

We have been running a geth 1.8 based private PoA chain for a long time. We are trying to upgrade it to geth 1.9.

After changing the command line arguments to reflect the new API and remove deprecated switches, we managed to get everything back up and running - but something doesn't look right.

When running read-only queries against the chain (Eg calling a `public view` method on a contract from our Dapp), the chain responds with:

`insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

We havn't changed anything on our Dapp frontend, and we using the same version of Metamask that we're using against our 1.8 chain.

What could we be doing wrong?

EDIT: Note that when reading from the chain using tools like truffle, it works. Only Metamask seems to have trouble.